# Interactive plot – return value of selected point

Tags: r

The code below is used to plot a two dimension plot.

```
plot(1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=c(-1, 1), ylim=c(-1, 1))
for (i in 1:100) {
  x<-cos(i)
  y<-sin(i)
  points(x,y)

}
```

What I want to implement is that when I click one point on the plot, it can tell me the value of `x, y, i`. Please, note that I must keep using the `for` loop to add the points into the plot, so do not delete the `for` loop.

How can I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: what have tried already?

Comment: You probably would like to look into the possibilities of the `plotly` package.

Comment: Could you please post what you have tried, then we can fix your errors!

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to click on the plot and get information from a given element, `identify()` should suffice.

```
plot(1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=c(-1.1, 1.1), ylim=c(-1.1, 1.1))

i <- 1:50
x <- cos(i/50*pi*2)
y <- sin(i/50*pi*2)

points(x, y, cex=0.8, pch=16, col="hotpink")

id <- identify(x, y, n=4, cex=0.8, 
  labels=paste(round(x, 2), round(y, 2), i, sep=", "))
```

Press esc or right-click the plotting window to stop.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks. But it seems  run very slow. If  I run the `for` loop for 2000 times, it can be very very long.....

Comment: @jack: Why would you want to loop it?

Comment: Hi, I must use the `for` loop in my real project.

Comment: @jack: Why? To what end?

Comment: Hi, because  I need the `for` loop to sample something in the real project....  it takes a long time to run the identity function. I do not know why..... In this case, there are only 50 points..........

Comment: The result is what I want. Just the code runs very slow........

Comment: You definitely do not want to run `identify()` inside a loop. That would make no sense, as it's an interactive function (requires user input). If you want to add text to the plot automatically, have a look at `text()`.

Comment: Hi, there are about 20000 points that are all in a small area. And if I use `text()`, I cannot distinguish which point the text belongs to.....

Comment: @jack: Then you need to figure out how to either spread the points out, only select a few points a given distance apart, or in some other way improve the aesthetics. But that sounds like a separate question, and one that [likely has been answered before](https://www.google.com/search?ei=uAJ7W-efGaOUmwXkqpawAg&q=r+label+points+too+close).